# Rewriting with lighttpd - how to remove file extensions

Tags: http, lighttpd

I would like to use lighttpd's mod_rewrite to allow requests without a specific file extension. For instance, I would like the following mappings to automatically work:

- Requesting for "/index" would serve "/index.php".
- "/dir/file" => "/dir/file.php"
- "/dir/file?args" => /dir/file.php?args"

Can this be easily done with a single rewrite rule for a given extension (e.g. ".php")?

Answer (score 2):

Cassy and natbro got this very nearly right, but as user102008 commented, this erroneously rewrites any directory index.  Adding a url.rewrite-once matching anything ending with a '/' seems to make it work.

```
url.rewrite-once = (  "^(.*)/$" => "$1/" )
url.rewrite-if-not-file = ( "^([^?]*)(\?.*)?$" => "$1.php$2" )
```

Comment: But what about redirecting directory names that are missing a trailing slash?

Answer (score 1):

Without having tested it, but you can give it a shot:

```
url.rewrite-once = ( 
  "^([^?]*)(\?.*)?$" => "$1.php$2",
)
```

Basically it means

- take everything but a question mark
- and, if exists, take the question mark and everything following

and you rewrite it to the first part, include the `.php` and add the last part again.

Again: I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: wouldn't this cause the root directory ("/") to be rewritten to "/.php"?

Answer (score 0):

[cassie's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774109/rewriting-with-lighttpd-how-to-remove-file-extensions/1924710#1924710) is just about right. i would suggest dropping the trailing comma and using [url-rewrite-if-not-file](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs:ModRewrite) (available since 1.4.x lighttpd). this lets you serve other files that exist in the same directory without them getting rewritten.

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file = ( "^([^?]*)(\?.*)?$" => "$1.php$2" )
```

Comment: wouldn't this cause the root directory ("/") to be rewritten to "/.php", since it's not a file?

Answer (score -1):

yes

^(.*).php $1 [L,R,NC,QSA]

that would be for .htaccess in a directory

^/(.*).php http://same.site/$1 [L,R,NC,QSA]

where your domain is 'same.site' because it needs to redirect for the URL to change (as opposed to proxy)

Comment: That seems like the correct approach using Apache's mod_rewrite. However, I am looking for a solution for lighttpd.

Comment: err, sorry I thought the pattern & syntax were the same

I've only dabbled with lighttpd

http://forum.lighttpd.net/topic/504