# Lighttpd rewrite .php?

Tags: php, webserver, lighttpd

I need to remove the ".php" from showing in the URL. Can anyone tell me how I'd achieve this in the webserver's configuration? Also, is it possible with mod_simple_vhost enabled, to change this behaviour based on what site it's serving?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774109/rewriting-with-lighttpd-how-to-remove-file-extensions

Comment: Nope, I looked at that one. Not the same.

Comment: It _is_ the same as far as I can see.... You just output HTML with urls without the '.php', and add it in with the rewrite at that link. Or do you need 301-moved redirects to fix old links?

Comment: For example, if I had http://domain.com/login.php?act=register, I want to make it http://domain.com/login?act=register. I'm a programmer, but I don't really know much about the webservers, rewrite rules etc. and haven't really got time at the moment to look through lighttpd's docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression in the rewrite rule:

```
 url.rewrite-once = (
     "^/login(\?.*)$" => "login.php$1"
 }
```

Comment: Can I rewrite url with php file without the url.rewrite-once?